# Python: How to calculate correlation in the case

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file to generate day to day. Usually the file row count is stable i.e. 10K records but for certain days, it would spike to a higher number i.e. 20K or 30K. I need to analyze what factor caused the data volume increase, and it could be various reasons in different days.
I want to use python to do some preliminary analysis to save the time. The file has around 100 columns and I know 5 of these columns are usually the reason. It could be one of the column or the combination of multiple columns.
Say I have below data for 3 days:

```
import pandas as pd
df_day1 = pd.DataFrame([["a1", "b1"], ["a2", "b2"]], columns = ["A", "B"])
df_day2 = pd.DataFrame([["a1", "b1"], ["a2", "b2"], ["a3", "b3"], ["a4", "b4"]], columns = ["A", "B"])
df_day3 = pd.DataFrame([["a1", "b1"], ["a2", "b2"], ["a1", "b3"], ["a1", "b4"]], columns = ["A", "B"])
```

Then if I compare day 1 and day 2: I want to draw the conclusion it's due to the increase of both column A and column B.
If I compare day 1 and day 3: I want to draw the conclusion it's due to the increase of column B
In real case it could be much complex as there could be thousands of combinations.
My first step is to run a combination of the columns related and count the distinct value of each combination - but I have no clue what's next?

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations

def get_column_combinations(candidate_columns):
    columns_list = []
    for idx in range(1, len(candidate_columns)+1):
        comb = list(combinations(candidate_columns, idx))
        comb = [[item for item in tup] for tup in comb]
        columns_list = columns_list + comb
    return columns_list

def get_file_stat_details(df, columns):
    size_grp = df.groupby(by=columns).count()
    column = size_grp.columns[0]
    size_grp = size_grp[column].reset_index().rename(columns={column: "Count"})
 
    total_count = size_grp.shape[0]
    
    columns = ",".join(columns)
    return [filename, columns, max_count, min_count, mean_count,median_count, total_count ]

candidate_columns = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
```